# setup webos list selector choices with ajax json response dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, list, webos

I'm trying to develop an application which gets the the response from the MySQL database using ajax post and update in list selector, but the list is displaying empty, can some one help me out from this please.....

code for .js:

```
SecondAssistant.prototype.setup = function() {
this.selectorChanged = this.selectorChanged.bindEventListener(this);
Mojo.Event.listen(this.controller.get('firstselector'), Mojo.Event.propertyChange,     this.selectorChanged);

this.names = [];

try {
    new Ajax.Request('http://localhost/projects/testingasdf.php', {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: {
        'recs': getallrecords,
        'q': q
        },
        evalJSON: 'true',
        onSuccess: function(response){
            var json = response.responseJSON;
            var count = json.count - 1;

            for(i=0; i<count; i++){
                this.names.push({
                    label: json[i].name,
                    value: '0'
                });
            }
                       this.controller.modelChanged(this.model);
        }.bind(this),
        onFailure: function(){
            Mojo.Controller.errorDialog('Failed to get ajax response');

        }

    });

}
catch (e){
    Mojo.Controller.errorDialog(e);
}

this.controller.setupWidget("firstselector",
          this.attributes = {
              label: $L('Name'),
              modelProperty: 'currentName'
          },
          this.model = {
              choices: this.names
          }
        ); 

};
```

code for php:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');  // this is the magic that sets responseJSON


$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')// creating a connection



mysql_select_db("test", $conn) or die('could not select the database');//selecting database from connected database connection

switch($_POST['recs'])
{
    case'getallRecords':{
        $q = $_POST['q'];

        //performing sql operations
        $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name= $q");
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed:' .mysql_error());
        $all_recs = array();
        while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $all_recs[] = $line;
        }
        break;
        }   
        }

echo json_encode($all_recs);

// Free resultset
mysql_free_result($result);


// closing connection
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: i was trying the same but b=use remote hosted server .. local host is not working for me :(

Answer (score 1):

I would move the model updating code out of the SecondAssistant.prototype.setup method and have it fire somewhere in SecondAssistant.prototoype.activate.

Also call modelChanged

```
this.controller.modelChanged(this.model);
```

There is a typo on bindEventListener - should be bindAsEventListener and the return of the bind should be a different object:

```
this.selectorChangedBind = this.selectorChanged.bindAsEventListener(this);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, i have added the this.controller.modelChanged(this.model);

Comment: I have modified the code and updated it but log message is showing some errors
error: Error: Cannot call method 'bindAsEventListener' of undefined, line undefined, file undefined
warning: WidgetController: Could not instantiate widget ' firstselector ', since it has not been set up.
any suggestions please....:(

Comment: @raj - review edited answer on bindEventListener should be bindAsEventListener and the object should be a different variable.